# Python Dictionary type error

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

i have a dictionary like follows:

```
Dict = { "key1" : {"subkey1" : "value1" , "subkey2" : "value2" , 

         "key2" : {"subkey1" : "value3" , "subkey2" : "value4 }
```

I basically want to be able to check for values as follows

```
if (Dict[key][any_subkey] == "value"):

   do something....
```

i am getting the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str....

Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: What is `Dict[key]` when you get this `TypeError`?

Comment: It looks like your definition of `Dict` and your actual implementation are not alligned.  either `Dict` or `Dict[key]` is a `list`.

Comment: What is Dict[key] when you get this TypeError?....It is a variable string same as the key

Comment: Can you copy and paste your actual code? The code you posted has several obvious syntax errors.

Comment: Pls do paste correct code. your parenthesis is not even close properly

Comment: what are the obvious syntax error you see. My code is same as here

Comment: No, what you posted won't run due to the typos. If you typed in the code by hand when writing your question, please don't do that. Copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> Dict = { "key1" : {"subkey1" : "value1" , "subkey2" : "value2"} , 
...          "key2" : {"subkey1" : "value3" , "subkey2" : "value4" }}
>>> Dict["key1"]
{'subkey2': 'value2', 'subkey1': 'value1'}
>>> Dict["key1"]["subkey1"]
'value1'
>>>
```

Have you checked your syntax?

Comment: dict = { "key1" : {"subkey1":"val1" , "subkey2":"val2"}}..this is how my declaration is. The one you pasted will work

Comment: So you made it work? In your example, you're missing a closing } on the first line, before the comma, and another one at the end of the second line.

Comment: Based on your error message, it might also be an issue with scope or initialising two structures with the same name - try renaming your Dict variable to something else, e.g. myDict and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
>>> Dict = { "key1" : {"subkey1" : "value1" , "subkey2" : "value2" ,
... 
...                    "key2" : {"subkey1" : "value3" , "subkey2" : "value4" }
...                              }
...          }
>>> print Dict["key1"]["key2"]["subkey2"] == "value4"
True
```

Comment: NO i want Dict["key1"]["subkey1"]